What can a photographer do if the client does not like the editing?
Currently there is a case between a bride and a wedding photographer going viral which has been named "sepia gate". To make this an somewhat abstract learning, here is a very rough summary of what seems to have taken place:

A bride has booked a wedding photographer. Pricing was allegedly around $8000. (Price named to give an idea on expectations)
The client was aware of the editing style of the photographer and even described it herself as golden and airy. The instagram and portfolio of the photographer showed a style leaning into very warm color temperatures.
After the wedding, the photographer delivered more than 2000 images edited in her style.
The client first thanked her and stated she found them beautiful.
After around 30 days, the client found that the warm editing skewed the colors so much from their true tones, that it bothered her. Especially as a make-up artist herself, she found her make-up and skin tones not represented well.
She then requested changes, which were done, although not to the client's satisfaction. It is clear that at this part, there was a lack of good communication, so edits were made, but not towards the client's vision.
After some back and forth frustration on both sides grew. The client asked for the RAWs of some photos, which the photographer provided as a sign of good will.
The client edited the RAWs to their taste. Which was a more natural, true tone look.
A last call between client and photographer ended with the client wanting all RAWs and the photographer stating a price of $3000 for the RAWS for personal use only or $4000 for fully transferring any rights on the RAWs.
At that point communication stopped and the client took the case to tiktok, showing her edits vs the photographer's edits on the RAWs given and blaming her to "hold her photos hostage". The client also made clear that she was aware that getting any RAWs is highly unusual but made clear that she also felt entitled to them for a small fee (she mentions $1000 for them as reasonable).

While there are many opinions about the case, where definitely both parties could have handled the situation more constructively, I think there is something to learn from it, if you ever encounter such a case.
So how can a photographer handle a situation like this constructively?

At least the photographer is not dealing with a lawyer for a client who had no intention of paying for anything , no matter how well done it was. I know wedding photogs who will absolutely never accept a job if the bride, groom, or any of their parents are attorneys. Basically, too many are willing to very publicly ruin the reputation of the photog they wanted/hired in order to get away with paying nothing or even extorting more from them.

Communicating your Style
Just bring your personal style actively into the contract talks, if that is a strict thing for you. A client might not be aware that the style that you show off on your portfolio IS in fact what they can expect. If you have a very definite editing style that is your brand, just communicate this before. It might sound obvious to you, but it might not be for the client.
If you are set on your style, which is totally ok, then make sure that you include an Artistic Style Clause in your contract, describing your stlye and setting clear boundaries how far you are willing to stray from that style. This way you are at least on the safe side legally. And just for reference, In the case mentioned, the photographer had this, as far as I understood.
Avoiding miscommunication about style afterwards
While disliking the style of a photographer after the fact is really unfortunate, a lot of the problems could have been avoided after the first request of re-edits.
Listen to the client! Try to find out what the client really dislikes, even if it hurts the ego. Ask for an example of an image which style the client likes better. A lot of clients are not very good at describing what they want. If you have an example image, it is a lot easier.
Then edit ONE image based on that.
Get the client's approval. Make sure to state that this is the only free edit run through the images - then apply that style to the rest of the images.
Giving out RAWs
The main trouble started, when giving out RAW files. I can only highly discourage you from that. With that well-meant gesture you can easily dig your own grave. The client will suddenly know that they can get the RAWs and will probably pursue that idea.
If you feel comfortable with giving out RAWs, at least consider a contract, what can and cannot be done with the RAWs. You may not want edits that are not representing your work out there with credit to your name. You may also want to rule out commercial use.
In this specific case, the unhappiness of the client obviously grew as with the RAW she noticed how far the stylized edit went from the true to color base. So if you are doing very heavy edits, keep this in mind.
How to work with a shitstorm
If your client for any reason decides to make a social media mess out of the situation, I would recommend consulting a lawyer. There is a fine line between a valid bad review from a client to slandering and depending on the case, it might be good to have that checked.
However you feel about it: Refrain to answer in public in the same way. Shitstorms usually only escalate if both sides feed it. You can just weather it out. In the case of Sepia Gate, the photographer did a very clever thing by keeping silent, and only doing one interview about the case.


Delivering 3,000 photos is ridiculous. I believe it is poor branding for a photographer, who is delivering art, with a particular style. Part of wedding photography is the specialness and uniqueness of the moment, and the delivered package should reflect that. 3,000 photos doesn't speak to a curated collection. What's more, stylistic edits to 3,000 photos screams (from a branding viewpoint) batch processing, rather than special attention to the best of the best.
I would recommend photographers submit a un-processed proof set, out of the 3,000 or so photos (after culling obviously bad shots), with large "DRAFT"-style watermarking on them, to the client. Let the client be part of the process of down-selecting the best of the best. Let them curate the choice, and give them the option for additional 10–25 photos for extra pricing. I would recommend around 300 or so as a standard wedding package. 500 if the guest list is particularly large and the client wants to make sure they have photos with their 3rd cousin twice removed's aunt Clara.
This protects the wedding photographer by limiting the sheer amount of re-work.

Let the client make the tone selection choices If the client objects to the delivered edited style, as the Sepia Bride did, rather than make assumptions and complete edits without getting clear communication of the desired output, you should create a tone chart of 2 or 3 example photos, of the client's choice, and make several edits all of them. Maybe 3–5 different options of saturation, tone, true-tone, color correction, etc. Let the client guide those tone edit picks. With the client's direction, make 2 or 3 edits (of each of the 3 chosen shots) within those tonal ranges, presenting that choice to the client. Apply that final tone choice to maybe 20 shots, to get final approval from the client before editing the full set of delivered 300-ish shots.

Never, ever, ever, give out RAWs. The only reason to deliver RAWs is if the client pays for copyright ownership (for a substantial additional charge). Once you give out RAWs, you lose a lot of control of claiming your style or branding. If you're willing to completely sell copyright and publishing rights to the client, then delivering the RAWs is not a major problem. But if you're going to do that, you're diminishing your value as a wedding photographer.



Good points, thanks!
